I can't export multiple animations properly from Blender/Mixamo to USDZ for RealityKit properly
I'm working on a final assignment consisting in a RealityKit game and I'm so desperate finding a way to make the 3D models and animations work but I can't find tutorials or anything useful. I made a 3D model of a character in Vroid Studio, exported it to Mixamo once I erased the armature and prepared the textures via Blender. I downloaded several animations as FBX from the service and the most challenging thing is making my character change animation in my app. But any possible approach has problems I cannot solve or understand.

I tried fusing all animations togethers in an NLA track in Blender, but when I exported to FBX and moved to Reality Converter, despite the model looks as intended, only 10 frames of the whole animation are played and this remains in the app and happens regardless of the first animation in the NLA track, and when I try to change the animation, those 10 frames of the idle animation remain. I tried exporting to GLFB and the model exported the animations well and despite it turned out bigger and with missing textures that I could fix, the model is invisible in my RealityKit app even if it appears as intended in Xcode's USDZ viewer.

My NLA track

All Mixamo animations are properly exported to USDZ individually so the other approach was loading each animation individually and changing the animation of the model, but it was not possible. This warning appears every time I try and I can't find any way to solve it: Cannot find a BindPoint for any bind path: "", "run.mixamorig_Hips", "run.mixamorig_Hips.SkeletalPose.SkeletalPoses[0]". I don't understand why I get this error because both files use the exact same model and I downloaded from the same source.

Assuming my models model_idle.usdz and model_run.usdz, I load the model here:
var characterAnims = [String : AnimationResource]()
var characters = [ModelEntity?]()

func loadModel(from url: URL, anchorEntity: AnchorEntity, name: String) {
        var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
        
        cancellable = ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(contentsOf: url)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: {completion in
                switch (completion) {
                case .finished:
                    print("Model \(name) succesfully loaded")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error loading model \(name): \(error)")
                }
                cancellable?.cancel()
            }, receiveValue: { (model: Entity) in
                if let model = model as? ModelEntity {
                    if self.characters.first??.name == name { return }
                    model.name = name
                    
                    // Animations
                    if let animation = model.availableAnimations.first {
                        model.playAnimation(animation.repeat(duration: .infinity), transitionDuration: 0.1, startsPaused: false)
                        // Individual animations
                        for animType in CharAnimation.allCases {
                            let id = animType.animId(character: model.name)
                            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: id, withExtension: "usdz", subdirectory: "3DModels.scnassets") else {
                                print("\(id) animation file not found")
                                continue
                            }
                            let anim = try! ModelEntity.load(contentsOf: url)
                            self.characterAnims[id] = anim.availableAnimations.first!
                            print("\(id)")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Registrate
                    anchorEntity.addChild(model)
                    self.characters.append(model)
                    ARSessionManager.shared.arView?.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
                }
            })
    }

The CharAnimation enum:
enum CharAnimation: Int, CaseIterable {
    case idle = 0, run
    
    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .idle:
            return "Idle"
        case .run:
            return "Run"
        }
    }
    
    func animId(character: String) -> String {
        return "\(character)_\(self.name)"
    }
}

The function to change animation:
func changeAnim(character: Entity, anim: CharAnimation) {
        let id = anim.animId(character: character.name)
        print ("Requesting \(id)")
        guard let requestAnim = characterAnims[id] else {
            print ("Requested \(id) doesn't exist")
            return
        }
        character.playAnimation(requestAnim, transitionDuration: 0.5, startsPaused: false)
    }

EDIT: I had an idea and tried to import my animations to Blender and then export from there so the skeleton is the exact same, and now the warning has disappeared at the very least. Still, I'm trying this code sample for testing it doesn't behave as expected. It works well when the animations aren't repeated in a loop, but when I use the repeat() function it won't transition as I want to and refuses to play the run animation. Thank goodness that now the skeleton issue is solved thanks to that idea of mine.
